# trying to include nlohmann/json.hpp

Tags: c++, json, cmake, nlohmann-json

OS environment is Centos 8 g++ version 8.5

and for Ubuntu 22.0 g++ 11.3.0

I have a nagging issue, which doesn't rear its head when I build on Ubuntu.

I'm finding that for my centos build in order for the the compiler to find the 'json.hpp'
I have to include the full path in the include
`#include </usr/include/nlohmann/json.hpp>`

whereas in the Ubuntu build I only need
`#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>`

I've tried several things like
using include_directories("/usr/include")
target_include_directories(blah blah)
but the only thing that seems to get it to compile is adding the full path.

Have anyone else experienced this issue?
And would the compiler version be the issue

This is a general question.
I appreciate any help or previous experience, but don't ask for code as none will be given.

Comment: There is a single header version, so is adding it directly to your code base an option?

Comment: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17966

Comment: you're presumably not using the system's built in compiler, it probably deliberately doesn't look in `/usr/include`, `/usr/include` is only intended for system headers, libraries you've installed yourself should be in `/usr/local/include`

Comment: You should have installed your package in this location `/usr/local/include/`. This is [the proposed standard for Linux Operating Systems](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) including [CentOS](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ(2f)General.html#Why_is_the_CentOS_Project_taking_over_my_Website.3F).